# How to sort numbers in strings in python

Tags: python, dictionary, formatted

sorry... my English is not very good... so i didn't know How to ask this question... please just read so u can understand what i want...
I have a def which takes a dictionary:

```
{'John':30.370, 'Mike':84.5, 'Sara':97.55, 'Frank': 75.990}
```

And i wanna return this:

```
Sara       97.55
Mike       84.50
Frank      75.99
John       30.37
```

But My solution don't return this!
My solution:

```
def formatted(a):
    s=''
    for i in a:
        d='{0:<10s}{1:>6.2f}\n'.format(i, a[i])
        s=s+d
    s=s.rstrip()  
    return s
a={'John':30.370, 'Mike':84.5, 'Sara':97.55, 'Frank': 75.990}
print (formatted(a))
```

it returns:

```
John       30.37
Mike       84.50
Sara       97.55
Frank      75.99
```

I should sort these numbers...But i Have no idea How to do that!
Anybody can help??

Comment: Dictionaries aren't sorted, you need an `OrderedDict`

Comment: You need to sort the dict keys by the values.  e.g. `for i in sorted(a, key=a.get)`

Comment: i am new in python... can u show me how can i use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one line :

```
d = {'John': 30.370, 'Mike': 84.5, 'Sara': 97.55, 'Frank': 75.990}
print(
    "\n".join(
        '{0:<10s}{1:>6.2f}'.format(k, v) for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    )
)

Sara       97.55
Mike       84.50
Frank      75.99
John       30.37
```

Explanation :

- first, sort the dictionary according to the value : `sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)` => [sorted method in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted)
- then, apply the format to all the sorted items => [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- finally, use `"\n".join()` to regroup and format everybody in one string separated by `\n` => [join method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join)
- at the end, everything is printed by the print() method

Comment: Can you explain this: print("\n".join('{0:<10s}{1:>6.2f}'.format(k, v) for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)))                                                                     verbosely?

Comment: line one line:)) lol

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = {'John':30.370, 'Mike':84.5, 'Sara':97.55, 'Frank': 75.990}
>>> b = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> print b
[('John', 30.37), ('Frank', 75.99), ('Mike', 84.5), ('Sara', 97.55)]
```

for reverse

```
>>> c = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1] ,reverse=True)
>>> print c
[('Sara', 97.55), ('Mike', 84.5), ('Frank', 75.99), ('John', 30.37)]
```

for print use :

```
d = collections.OrderedDict(dict(c)) # c is upder dict
for i, v in d.items(): 
    _dict_pair='{0:<10s}{1:>6.2f}\n'.format(i, v)
    print(_dict_pair)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `sort` the dictionary on `values` using `sorted` and `[operator.itemgetter][1]`.

```
In [100]: _dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)) # d is your dictinory
    
In [101]: _dict
Out[101]: 
OrderedDict([('Sara', 97.55),
             ('Mike', 84.5),
             ('Frank', 75.99),
             ('John', 30.37)])
```

Then you need to use `collections.OrderedDict` as `dictionaries` are hash key pair.

```
for i, v in _dict.items():
       d='{0:<10s}{1:>6.2f}\n'.format(i, v)
       print(d)
```

> Sara       97.55
>
> Mike       84.50
>
> Frank      75.99
>
> John       30.37